# Execution of an exe consuming WCF Service is failing inside windows docker container

Tags: c#, wcf, docker-for-windows

I have a console application written in .NET framework 4.8. It consumes a .NET WCF web service with the help of a proxy at a given port 18793 which is hosted on the local machine as a console host service. The web service uses net.Tcp binding protocol.

Service Contract (POSTest)

```
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace PosTest
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IPosTestSvc
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetData(int value);
    }
}
```

Service Implementation

```
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace PosTest
{
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
    public class PosTestSvc : IPosTestSvc
    {
        public string GetData(int value)
        {
            return $"GetData Service method called with value {value}";
        }
    }
}
```

Proxy for the Service where WebReference to the hosted service is added :-

```
using PosTest.Proxy.WcfSvcRef;
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;

namespace PosTest.Proxy
{
    public class PosDeploymentDefaultProxy
    {
        public int ClientDataValue { get; set; }
        public string GetData
        {
            get
            {
                var binding = GetEndPointBinding();
                var address = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("net.tcp://mylenovo:18793/PostTest/DeploymentDefault"), EndpointIdentity.CreateSpnIdentity(""));
                IPosTestSvcChannel client = ChannelFactory<IPosTestSvcChannel>.CreateChannel(binding,address);
                return client.GetData(ClientDataValue);
            }
        }

        private static Binding GetEndPointBinding()
        {
            Binding binding = new NetTcpBinding();
            ((NetTcpBinding)binding).MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647;
            ((NetTcpBinding)binding).MaxBufferSize = 2147483647;
            ((NetTcpBinding)binding).MaxBufferPoolSize = 2147483647;

            binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 120, 0);
            binding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 120, 0);
            return binding;
        }
    }
}
```

Finally the above Proxy is used as a reference to the client console app :-

```
using PosTest.Proxy;
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace PosTest.Client
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var c = new PosDeploymentDefaultProxy();
            string x = "";
            if (args.Count() == 0)
            {
                x = "0";
            }
            else
            {
                x = args[0];
            }
            c.ClientDataValue = Convert.ToInt32(x);
            Console.WriteLine(c.GetData);
        }
    }
}
```

When this console app is executed within the windows docker container created out of the image: `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8.1` where I am manually copying the "POSTestClient" exe binaries into the container and executing the exe as below in powershell :-

```
cmd /c PosTest.Client.exe 7843
```

then I get the following error.

```
PS C:\POS\PosTestClient> cmd /c PosTest.Client.exe 7843

Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The socket connection was aborted. 
This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. 
Local socket timeout was '01:59:53.5154850'. ---> System.IO.IOException: 
The write operation failed, see inner exception. ---> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The socket connection was aborted. 
This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. 
Local socket timeout was '01:59:53.5154850'. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Send(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, Boolean immediate, TimeSpan timeout)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, Boolean immediate, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedConnection.WriteNow(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, BufferManager bufferManager)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedConnection.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, Boolean immediate, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.StartWriting(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.ProcessWrite(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.ProcessWrite(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamConnection.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, Boolean immediate, TimeSpan timeout)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace:
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamConnection.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, Boolean immediate, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.SendPreamble(IConnection connection, ArraySegment`1 preamble, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.DuplexConnectionPoolHelper.AcceptPooledConnection(IConnection connection, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionPoolHelper.EstablishConnection(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOpenOnce.System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ICallOnce.Call(ServiceChannel channel, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOnceManager.CallOnce(TimeSpan timeout, CallOnceManager cascade)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EnsureOpened(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]:
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at PostTest.Proxy.WcfSvcRef.IPosTestSvc.GetData(Int32 value)
   at PostTest.Proxy.PosDeploymentDefaultProxy.get_GetData() in D:\Project\WCfMyLocalService\PostTest.Proxy\PosDeploymentDefaultProxy.cs:line 18
   at PosTest.Client.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\Project\WCfMyLocalService\PosTest.Client\Program.cs:line 22
```

Somehow inside the container the .NET WCF service is not able to resolve at the given port i.e., 18793.

In this investigation of the issue everything is setup on the local machine (i.e., my laptop) but in the actual application the service is hosted on a separate windows webserver within an intranet space. This is just a sample application for illustration purposes, so the output expected is just a string with the number values provided as an argument. For example, "PosTest.Client.exe 10" -> Output -> GetData Service method called with value 10.

Comment: What do you expect `net.tcp://mylenovo:18793/PostTest/DeploymentDefault` to do from within the docker container? And why do I have to dig through your github repository to find that trivia?

Comment: @rene apologies for the github repo. Inability to explain the whole code structure I put a link to github repo. As for the net.tcp service, I am not doing this directly within the container. Please consider this as a call to a webservice which is consumed by the console app and trying to call an API endpoint to get some result from the service.

Comment: You say *this console app is executed within the windows docker container*. That app uses the proxy that has that net.tcp url in it. Unless you've setup routing / dns I don't see how it would resolve the mylenovo host from within the container.

Comment: Wouldn’t the container and the host laptop be part of the same domain ? If not, any pointers on how to achieve this please.

Comment: @rene I tried to check whether the host is getting resolved by using svcutil command and downloading the metadata - `svcutil net.tcp://mylenovo:18794/PostTest/mex` which returned me no error. It downloaded the metadata and generating output - 

`Attempting to download metadata from 'net.tcp://mylenovo:18794/PostTest/mex' using WS-Metadata Exchange. This URL does not support DISCO.
Generating files...
C:\POS\PosTestClient\PosTestSvc.cs
C:\POS\PosTestClient\output.config` . Could this tell us that it is able to resolve the host MYLENOVO

Comment: if you ran that svcutil command from within the docker container then I'm out of options.

Comment: yes.. I did run it within the docker container.

Comment: @hi_shobhit76 I am having the  same issue. Did you figure it out?

Comment: @user9969157 - no answers to this yet :(